# sed behavior with & (ampersand)

Tags: sed

Trying to clean up some xml text that looks like

```
Forest & Paper Products Manufacturing
```

with a sed command like

```
 sed "s/ \& / &amp; /"
```

but once sed gets done with the file, my output looks like

```
Forest & amp; Paper Products Manufacturing
```

Can't figure out why sed is putting a space after the &

I can solve this with:

```
sed "s/ \& / \&amp; /"
```

But why do I need to quote the & with a \ prefix

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in the replacement part, `&` indicates the matched string `\0`. So if you want to have literal `&` in replacement part, you have to escape it.

E.g

```
kent$ (master|✔) echo "foo"|sed 's/.*/&_bar/'   
foo_bar

kent$ (master|✔) echo "foo"|sed 's/.*/\&_bar/' 
&_bar
```

related info taken from sed's INFO page:

```
   The REPLACEMENT can contain `\N' (N being a number from 1 to 9,
 inclusive) references, which refer to the portion of the match which
 is contained between the Nth `\(' and its matching `\)'.  Also, the
 REPLACEMENT can contain unescaped `&' characters which reference the
 whole matched portion of the pattern space
```

and

```
To include a literal `\', `&', or newline in the final replacement, be   
 sure to precede the desired `\', `&', or newline in the REPLACEMENT with 
 a `\'.
```

Comment: But how to replace & with \& if you don't know the replacement text in advance? I need to replace the replacement text before I want to replace it with sed? :D

Comment: echo "&EMAIL&" | sed -e "s/&/\\\\&/g"; returns "\&EMAIL\&"