# Using sed command replace in the input text file all occurrences of characters '&', '<', '>' with their HTML entities

Tags: sed, html-entities, ampersand

this is my input text file

```
< > & * ^ % $ # @ ! ) ( ) < > < > > > <
```

This is the sed shell script that I am using.

```
sed 's/&/&amp;/g ; s/</&lt;/g ; s/>/&gt;/g' html_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

This is the output file:

```
<lt; >gt; &amp; * ^ % $ # @ ! ) ( ) <lt; >gt; <lt; >gt; >gt; >gt; <lt;
```

I can't understand that why there is still `<` and `>` signs instead of `&`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed behavior with & (ampersand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750591/sed-behavior-with-ampersand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `info sed`:

```
3.3 The 's' Command
[...]
The 's' command (as in substitute) is probably the most important in
'sed' [...]. The syntax of the 's' command is 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.
[...]
The REPLACEMENT can contain [...] unescaped '&' characters which reference the
whole matched portion of the pattern space.
```

Escape `&` with `\` to `\&`.